# Fetch data from RSS and bind to a asp control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have to display weather details of a perticular city in a asp control as a widget. I hope i can get the weather details as rss feed data. Here how to bind this data to a asp control?. I need to show next 10 days weather details also.

Comment: Any updates for below answers?

Comment: Pankaj : I am trying to read the data from [link](http://www.findlocalweather.com/forecast/il/chicago.html). But getting error: _'>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 4, position 62._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. You can use your desired attributes. I used Date, Title, Description, 
Link

```
 internal class RssItem
    {
        public DateTime Date;
        public string Title;
        public string Description;
        public string Link;
    }

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
private Collection<RssItem> feedItems = new Collection<RssItem>();
xmlDoc.Load("URL of the RSS Feeds");
ParseRssItems(xmlDoc);

private void ParseRssItems(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
        {
            this.feedItems.Clear();
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item"))
            {
                RssItem item = new RssItem();
                this.ParseDocElements(node, "title", ref item.Title);
                this.ParseDocElements(node, "description", ref item.Description);
                this.ParseDocElements(node, "link", ref item.Link);
                string date = null;
                this.ParseDocElements(node, "pubDate", ref date);
                DateTime.TryParse(date, out item.Date);
                this.feedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialize the RSS xml to an object and databind a repeater to the items collection in that object.  Simple and works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Use [RSStoolkit](http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/)
Easy to use and flexible  [Use this sample](http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Consuming%20With%20RssDataSource&referringTitle=Consuming%20Feeds)